# DOS DIR - exclude files that start with string

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to get a list of files from a directory in DOS and I would like to exclude any files that START with "I_"

I can get it to exclude anything with I_ but that excludes it if it doesn't start with it. Here's my script >

```
dir /s /b c:\TEST | findstr /vi "\c:\TEST\I_." > c:\TEST\List.txt
```

Anyway to get "I_" to be excluded ONLY when it's the start of the word (ie I_TEST)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't exactly defined "word," but if you mean that a file or directory name begins a word, then adding the dirsep to the search string should do the trick.

```
dir /s /b c:\TEST | findstr /vi "\I_" > c:\TEST\List.txt
```

Comment: This will exclude any branch where the folder starts with `I_` and the question states *`exclude any files that start with I_`*

Comment: @MCND, like I said, _start of the word_ is not well defined. Directories are files, too, depending on whether or not you want them.